# Laravel Composer Installation Failed because it conflicts with another require

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to integrate Paystack payment platform to my project. But each time I run the command
`composer require wisdomanthoni/cashier-paystack`, it returns the following error.

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update wisdomanthoni/cashier-paystack
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires wisdomanthoni/cashier-paystack ^1.0 -> satisfiable by wisdomanthoni/cashier-paystack[v1.0.0].
    - wisdomanthoni/cashier-paystack v1.0.0 requires illuminate/database ~5.7.0|~5.8.0 -> found illuminate/database[v5.7.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: `wisdomanthoni/cashier-paystack` is a rather old package, you should search for something that is still maintained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually resolved the dependencies by importing the libraries into the project manually and also running a composer update command

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "importing the libraries manually"?

Comment: Copied the composer required files into the vendor folder and using the "composer update" command to resolve the dependencies to match the current laravel version

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it - also, you know that anything you've copied into the vendor folder by hand is gone after running the next round of `composer install`?

Answer (score 1):

[`Illuminate/Database`](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database) is currently at version `8.29.0`. This means you're installing some Laravel 5.x dependency (likely on Laravel 8.x), which might be incompatible - if not already abandoned. If you cannot find a current version, you'd likely have to fix what you have - or use it with Laravel 5.x.